# Code inside of an if statement running no matter what

Tags: java, android, listview, if-statement, adapter

I made an impossible argument in an if statement just to assure myself that something else could run, and it didn't. My code looks like this;

```
if (5 == 2) {
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           //run a bunch of code
        }
    });
}
```

Regardless of the fact that nothing in this if statement should run, when I click on of the list view things, it does. Does anyone see any problems with this?

Also, one more question, is it possible to have two adapters in one activity? I want to fill two TextViews with different data, but the problem is they are both in the same activity, and since its seemingly impossible to make two custom constructors in a custom ArrayAdapter class, I can't see how I can initialize another adapter.

Comment: What language is that? JS?

Comment: Also, please don't mark this post down :(

Comment: no im using android studio java

Comment: Asking not to down vote won't help. Instead, learn how to ask great questions. It won't take a day, but you'll grow from from it. Also, never, ever take it personal. No one is out to get you. just keep learning and keep smiling.

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve] for some info. There is more! Simply look around the site

Comment: I don't know java, but can you remove the brackets from 5 == 2?

Comment: I tried running it on my machine, and it throws a syntax error. Are you are it's Java, and do you get an error?

Comment: Oh it looks like I need to install JDK.. Never mind

Comment: Sorry :(. But yea its android studio

Comment: I don't get an error, but what do u mean remove brackets?

Comment: Like this: if 5 == 2

Comment: Yea I get an error cause that's not java syntax

Comment: Ok never mind. I know python

Comment: Try this: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display

Comment: Wait what do I do there?

Comment: Go here: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit and choose Java. then click on "visualize execution", then clicking forward again and again will show you the steps the computer takes to execute your code

Comment: Oh, Android Studio has like a bunch of custom classes and packages and stuff like that, so it doesn't look like it will translate well on that :/. Thanks though!

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yea, I tried editing some stuff as well, but I soon realized that the majority of the methods I override and stuff come from android studio

Comment: Also, add tags to your question so the right people find it quicker.

Comment: Oh yea I should have said android studio as one sorry

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Java or jdk, but if you want a solution written in python I can try :)

Comment: Lol no thank you but I do appreciate you talking and trying to help me and giving me tips :)

Comment: no problem. Code on!

Comment: What are you trying to do ? your question is not clear